# Override docker-compose's command then run original command

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose. I need to insert some behavior into a container's startup lifecycle. (Creating a custom image is overkill and I want to avoid that.)

Ordinarily I'd override the entrypoint (run my commands then run the original entrypoint), but for this image I cannot as it performs important work.

The order I want:

- entrypoint (I can't override this as it must run before my stuff)
- the stuff I want to run
- the original command (`php-fpm`)

So I tried this:

```
command: >
  my_extra_command_1
  my_extra_command_2
  php-fpm
```

and this:

```
command: my_extra_command_1; my_extra_command_2; php-fpm
```

and this:

```
command: ["my_extra_command_1", "my_extra_command_2", "php-fpm"]
```

None of these work because the container stops after my first command. It doesn't run all the commands.

What is the correct syntax?

---

BTW the image's Dockerfile is defined using exec form as follows:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

and the entrypoint script ends with `exec "$@"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to arrange to have a shell run your command.  Dockerfile syntax will automatically wrap commands in `sh -c` but Docker Compose won't.

```yaml
command: sh -c 'my_extra_command_1; my_extra_command_2; php-fpm'
```

If you use the list syntax that manually breaks this into words, the argument to `-c` is a single word

```yaml
command:
  - sh
  - -c
  - my_extra_command_1; my_extra_command_2; php-fpm
```

Comment: Thanks that works! One last thing, if the command is really long is it possible to split onto multiple lines like we can do elsewhere in yaml? For example this really long line: `command: sh -c 'command1; command2; command3; command4; command5; original_command'`. I tried using `command: sh -c' and `command: >` as the first lines but that syntax isn't correct.

Comment: In the second example here where `sh` and `-c` are on its own line, you can use the YAML block scalar syntax for the third argument; it would look like `- >-` on its own line and then the command on following lines.  You'd need to include a `;` at the end of each line/command.

Comment: If your startup sequence is that involved, though, writing it into a shell script and creating a derived image is probably more sustainable.